# keyboard scrolling on focused div in webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit

I've got this little jquery plugin. There are some images in a vertically scrollable div. I can click on this div and scroll it by using arrow keys.

If you take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/RJMFt/3/), you can see that I want observe if arrow key right/left is pressed and if so, jump to the next image. In Firefox and IE, the keyup() event is being called, and in safari and chrome it's not.

I have encountered several strange scrolling and focus behaviours in webkit browsers, but I don't know why the keyup() event is not being fired. If you have any idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add the `tabindex` attribute to your `div`-element and it will work. This is kind of a hack to make an otherwise not focusable element focusable, just like any `input` or `button`.

Depending on the value given to `tabindex`, it will behave diffrently:

- `0` will allow you to focus the element with the keyboard arrows and tab key
- `-1` will disable tabbing, but it will still be focusable
- Anything greater then `0` will allow you prioratize tab focusing, where `1` has the highest priority

I've updated the [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/RJMFt/20/) accordingly.

Comment: Great! Works as expected! Do you have any ideas why this is the fix for Webkit?

Comment: @Razvan, because Webkit is alot stricter when it comes to focusable elements. It's not enough to just trigger the focus event on the element to make it focusable.